# How to store a lot of files and restrict access to them using web service in JVM (Clojure) and Nginx?

Tags: java, nginx, clojure

I have a web service. I need to store and retrieve documents (pdf, docx, etc.). I use latest stable versions of Ubuntu, Nginx and JVM. Clojure is my programming language. As I know Nginx can cache file system data very well. I would like to allow access for some files and restrict for others depending on a user or other web service rules. For example I can allow access to a file and then restrict it for some time and then allow access again.

How to do it with Nginx or without Nginx?

P.S. I see such solution without Nginx:
1. I receive request from a client.
2. I choose can I response a file to the client according security rules.
3. If access is allowed I'll read a file from file system with RandomAccessFile (or another IO class) and return bytes directly to the client without Nginx.

Or I can store all the files in a single flat file (several gigabytes or terabytes) and offsets and metadata (id, file names, etc.) in a second file. I can store the second file in RAM. It's OK with growing size of data. But will it has good performance for reading? I think it has such advantage like very good writing performance on any file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:

1. using the ring handler on nginx-clojure (http://nginx-clojure.github.io),
2. For download file service: in the ring handler, a File object can be returned as the body of response , access control can be carried out in a content handler, you can also use a separate access handler.
3. For the upload service: using HTTP PUT simply, no file decoding, otherwise the use of form post, you need use wrap-multipart-params decode the file, such as https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/ File-Uploads.
4. After uploading files, stored files can use relative paths, e.g based on the  md5 string of the file,  first to the second character as a directory name, 3rd to 4th character as a secondary directory name, such as 23 / a3 / full-md5-as-file-name, 
   so files in the directory distributed more balanced.

Comment: In the 2nd do you mean just usage of ring without nginx-clojure?  Will the 4th work with several million files?

Comment: When you use ring handler for static file with nginx-clojure. It will benefit from  the strong static file service on nginx.

Comment: the 4th work can work well with million files because it will make the files in the same directory won't be too many.  If there 1 million files in the most cases  1M / 256 / 256 =  16 files in one directories. We really use this method to store more than 3 million  files.

Comment: If I understand you correctly nginx-clojure helps cache static files. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. When use nginx-clojure you can write content handler / access handler / header filter by java/groovy/clojure and use features from nginx. So when deploy static file services ring handler on nginx-clojure nginx will use zero copy system call 'sendfile'  to service the static files and nginx features such as gzip ,expires and etc. can also be used together.

Comment: It's really powerful. Thanks a lot!